# Warm up requests not working in Cloud Endpoints Objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I've been trying to get warm up requests to work in my Endpoints project using Objectify but nothing seems to be working. Is there something I missed? I tried two methods:

servlet:

```
 public class WarmUpServ extends HttpServlet {

        static {
            ObjectifyService.factory().register(CounterEnt.class);
            ObjectifyService.factory().register(CounterShard.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void init() throws ServletException {
            super.init();
        }

        @Override
        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException,IOException {

        }

        @Override
        public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        }
    }
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>warm-up</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.myapp.backend.WarmUpServ</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>warm-up</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/war-up</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And I also tried a listener:

```
public class WarmUpServListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ObjectifyService.factory().register(CounterEnt.class);
        ObjectifyService.factory().register(CounterShard.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.myapp.backend.WarmUpServListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Note: I need to register my entities this way because I have a dependency where it uses `ObjectifyService` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warmup requests are not guaranteed to be made.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/warmup-requests/

> If warmup requests are enabled for your application, App Engine
>   attempts to detect when your application needs a new instance and
>   initiates a warmup request to initialize a new instance. However,
>   these detection attempts do not work in every case. As a result, you
>   might encounter loading requests, even if warmup requests are enabled
>   in your app. For example, if your app is serving no traffic, the first
>   request to the app will always be a loading request, not a warmup
>   request.

Use a `ServletContextListener` instead; that will always be called once at each instance start.

Comment: Ok. How come my ServletContextListener above doesn't work though? Am I missing something in my code?

Comment: Your listener looks fine to my eyes. What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What is the bad behavior? Have you tried setting debugger breakpoints to make sure your code is getting called?